# setOnAction in JavaFX (with Scala) -- how does it work?

Tags: scala, javafx, handle

Here is the code:

```
numSixBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler[ActionEvent] {
  def handle(event: ActionEvent) = display.setText(display.getText + "6")
})
```

My question is, usually when you have a method, you call the method and pass in the parameters in parenthesis. But here, we never call the handle method, and we never pass in anything for the parameter (event :ActionEvent). So how does it work?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The event handler is a [callback function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)).

JavaFX runs an event processing loop which handles incoming event signals.  When an action event occurs on the button (the button is clicked), the JavaFX system will call the event handler by invoking the [`handle(event)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/EventHandler.html#handle-T-) function, passing the [ActionEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/ActionEvent.html) as a parameter to the event handler.

Such event callbacks are a very common aspect of all UI processing frameworks.

For further information, read up on [event processing in JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/processing.htm).

I suggest learning JavaFX using the Java API until you are quite comfortable with that API before advancing to ScalaFX (that's just my unsolicited personal opinion of the easiest way to learn JavaFX programming).